# ls in glorious 256 colours

Tags: ls, colors

Apart from the [ls colors solarized](https://github.com/seebi/dircolors-solarized) theme, is there any other ls colour themes out there that you would recommend for a dark background with a urxvt terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For dark terminals, I definitely recommend **zenburn** colorset. You will find examples for varuious applications, including `urxvt`, [if you do a websearch for "zenburn"](http://duckduckgo.com/?q=zenburn).